# Powershell to send EMAIL attaching last modified file details?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to create a PowerShell which can search folder and send mail for the last created file details for filename and size , The email part is working fine but i am unable to attach file size and name in the body

```
Set-Location Y:\It-dept\OracleBkp
$latest = Get-Childitem -file $path | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1
$size = Get-Childitem -file $latest | Select-Object Name, @{Name="MegaBytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}
$Username  = "<sender email>"
$EmailPassword = "<password>"
$EmailTo = <Receiver Mail> 
$EmailFrom   = <Sender EMail>
$Subject = Oracle Backup 
$Body=  $latest
$Body += $size
$SMTPServer  = "smtp.outlook.com"  
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

The above is sending an email with filename but size is not showing in the body.
Any support will be appreciated..Thanks in advance

Comment: *”I am unable to attach”*  in what way are you unable? Are you getting an error? Wrong value? Help us help you.

Comment: email body is blank

Comment: It appears you are trying to attach a file, not just information about the file. You'll need to use attachment, not body. Body is for text.

Comment: I need file name and size in the email body, attachement not required because the file is too big for email attachment

Comment: `$Body += $latest, $size`

Comment: @notjustme, it only shows filename in the body .. Size is somehow not appearing even if we use   $Body =  $size

Comment: No, `$Body = $size` was not what I suggested. You need to add both that way or otherwise force $Body to be an array.

Comment: $Body += $latest, $size  ,  this also shows empty body in message

Comment: Well, what do you get when you run the `$latest=get-childitem` and `$size=get-childitem` lines interactively. What is in those two variables?

Comment: Before I suggest anything else - did you intend to store the path in your first line of code in $path? I'm not seeing it being declared anywhere else but I just assumed you had just left that bit out at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this...

```
$TargetPath = 'C:\Temp\OracleBkp.txt'

$latest = Get-Childitem -file $TargetPath | 
Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | 
Select-Object Name, @{
    Name       = 'MegaBytes'
    Expression = {$PSItem.Length / 1MB}
} -First 1
# Results
<#
Name          MegaBytes
----          ---------
OracleBkp.txt         0
#>

$Username               = 'sender emai'
$EmailPassword          = '<password'
$EmailTo                = 'Receiver Mail'
$EmailFrom              = 'Sender EMail'
$Subject                = 'Oracle Backup'
$Body                   = "File details `n $latest"
$SMTPServer             = 'smtp.outlook.com'
$SMTPMessage            = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
$SMTPClient             = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl   = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword)
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```